# What does the pond do?

Tags: candy-box-2

I was at the lollipop farm, when all of a sudden, an option for me to "**dig a pond**" pops up. I don't want to waste *100,000* candies for no apparent reason, so can anyone tell me what it does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pond allows you to buy Lolligators for 1200 candies each. Lolligators can be fed candies, turning them into lollipops at a 1:1 ratio.

It's useful if you have a large amount of candies and want more lollipops instead.

Answer (score 2):

The pond, when bought, allows you to buy "Lolligators," or alligators who eat your candies in exchange for lollipops.

Answer (score -1):

The alligators when you buy the pond they cost 1200 candies you feed them candies if you have a lot and want lollipops instead you feed them and get lollipops in exchange for the candies