# Should I feed the mill or dig a pond in the Lollipop Farm?

Tags: candy-box-2

I'm not sure what the pond does but my friend tells me to feed the mill first.

Comment: We can tell you the differences between them, but we can't tell you which to choose. That's all your choice.

Comment: Partial duplicate of [What does the pond do?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142454/what-does-the-pond-do)

Answer (score 2):

Feeding the mill increases candy per second. Adding a pond and lolligators allows you to convert candies to lollipops, which you may, in turn, feed to the mill. Think of it as an investment.

Answer (score 0):

Feed the mill first because it lets you get more candies faster.